# Save entire JsonObject to a variable using the ReadJson command in Morphlines?

Tags: configuration, morphline

I've looked through the documentation for Morphlines (available at http://cloudera.github.io/cdk/docs/current/cdk-morphlines/morphlinesReferenceGuide.html), and by the looks of things there is no way to store an entire Json Object to a variable in Morphlines using the ReadJson{} command. I know that this is possible using the ReadLine{} command, and this code:

```
{
    addValues {
               value_raw : "@{message}"
              }
}
```

I was wondering if anybody knew a way of doing a similar command with ReadJson{} to store the whole event/object/message in a variable, or if this is only possible with ReadLine{}?

Failing that I was wondering if it was possible to use both ReadLine{} and ReadJson{} independently within the same Morphlines config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use:

```
addValues {
           value_raw : "@{_attachment_body}"
          }
```

to save the entire event/object/message to a variable. In the case that you are using the ReadJson command in Morphlines, all events are expected to reside inside a Json Object called "_attachment_body", and therefore you can assign the entire event's value to a variable.